# Sum does'nt work for multiply

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT    Sum((pvc.cpt_amount) * (pvc.unit)) AS billed_amount, 
          pvc.cpt_amount, 
          pvc.unit 
FROM      payment            AS pay 
LEFT JOIN patient_insurances AS pi 
ON        pay.who_paid = pi.id 
LEFT JOIN patient_visit_cpt AS pvc 
ON        ( 
                    pay.encounter_id = pvc.id 
          AND       pay.claim_id = pvc.claim_id ) 
LEFT JOIN patient_visit AS pv 
ON        pvc.visit_id = pv.id 
WHERE 
and       pi.insurance_id = 761 
AND       pay.created_at <= '2016-04-01 23:00:00' 
AND       pay.created_at >= '2016-03-31 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY  pay.check_number, 
          pv.attending_provider_id
```

> for **unit = 1 and cpt_amount = 145**, but output comes like
>   mulitplied with 4. like 1 * 145 = 580.. please any one give solution

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and desire output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: It sounds like your `GROUP BY` is incorrect or not precise enough. Have you tried running the query without `SUM`?

Comment: My guess is one of your joins is with a 1-to-many related table. For example, if you have four `pi` for every one `pay` you will be summing four copies of `pvc`

Comment: Also, it looks like something got lost in copying your query to this question, `WHERE and` is not valid.

Comment: If you select any column which is not in the `GROUP BY` list, you should not wonder about unexpected results.

Comment: Your GROUP BY should only include what your ultimately returning.  You're including columns from your JOIN.  That is why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Group By` might be wrong.

Also remove keyword `AND` after the `WHERE` Clause

Try below query

```
SELECT Sum((pvc.cpt_amount) * (pvc.unit)) AS billed_amount, 
       pvc.cpt_amount,pvc.unit 
FROM payment AS pay 
LEFT JOIN patient_insurances AS pi  ON pay.who_paid = pi.id 
LEFT JOIN patient_visit_cpt AS pvc ON(pay.encounter_id = pvc.id AND pay.claim_id = pvc.claim_id) 
LEFT JOIN patient_visit AS pv ON pvc.visit_id = pv.id 
WHERE pi.insurance_id = 761 AND pay.created_at <= '2016-04-01 23:00:00' 
      AND pay.created_at >= '2016-03-31 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY  pvc.cpt_amount,pvc.unit
```

Comment: `SELECT Sum((pvc.cpt_amount) * (pvc.unit))` and `GROUP BY  pvc.cpt_amount,pvc.unit` does not make sence.

Comment: am not trying  to get group by for cpt.amount and unit. but some looping or realtion may be wrong

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes `SELECT Sum((pvc.cpt_amount) * (pvc.unit)) and GROUP BY pvc.cpt_amount,pvc.unit` doesn't make sence  but `SELECT pvc.cpt_amount,pvc.unit and GROUP BY pvc.cpt_amount,pvc.unit` will make sence

Comment: Neither does a query which explicitly selects the sum of both while requiring the individual amounts.  I think it best that he provide an actual use case with a problem statement. Otherwise, not knowing what it is he really wants is problematic.

Comment: i yhave added ...works good..... (SELECT SUM(cpt_amount * unit) FROM patient_visit_cpt where id in 
 (SELECT encounter_id FROM payment where check_number = pay.check_number)) as bill_amt